# SymPy - How to check if two terms are equal but not identical

Tags: python, sympy

For my recent project I have to check using `sympy` if two terms are equal or identical.

**Example**:

- `x+2=5 and x+5=8` - these two terms are equal (equivalent) but they are not identical
- `x+2=5 and x+2=5` - these are equal and identical

**Question**:

Is it possible to differentiate between "equal" and "identical"? If so - how do I achieve this?

Comment: i am not sure what you want to do.

Comment: See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#equals-signs

Answer (score 4):

If you use `==` you will get an answer to the objects being structurally identical. To check mathematical equality involves some sort of simplification to make the two expressions structurally identical. For the equations you give, one might do any of the following:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x')
x
>>> a=Eq(x+2,5)
>>> b=Eq(x+5,8)
>>> a.equals(b)
False
>>> solve(a)==solve(b)
True
>>> a.lhs-a.rhs == b.lhs-b.rhs
True
>>> abs(a.lhs-a.rhs) == abs(b.rhs-b.lhs)
True
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It will work from shell. But I want to start the python script from PHP. Therefore I pass the parameters (a and b) to the python script: 
`a=sys.argv[1]`
`b=sys.argv[2]
a1=parse_expr(a, transformations=transformations, evaluate = False)
b1=parse_expr(b, transformations=transformations, evaluate = False)
print(a1.equals(b1)) `
but I do not get any response.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But note that many routines like `solve` have work-arounds for Eq that change them to an exression: eqn -> eqn.lhs - eqn.rhs. You can see above in the example how the two eqns gave False when compared with equals.